# Exception 'Index out of range'

Tags: asp.net

In my code I have a CheckboxList and I add it's items dynamically!  What I want is to save the text  but only from the **checked** CheckBoxes in a session because  I  will need it in my next form!

So I wanted to make some text and as you see I save the text from the checked checkboxes in a list with name  `myche`, But when I press the button to see the first item of this list - this code `lblProba.Text = myche[0];` gives me an exception 'Index out of range'. It seems that my list is empty.

```
public partial class FormEGN : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string mynewstring;
   //List<List<string>> mycheckedList = new List<List<string>>();
    List<string> myche = new List<string>();
    CheckBoxList mycheckbox = new CheckBoxList();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mynewstring = (string)Session["id2"];


        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlNumberTourists.Items.Add("1");
            ddlNumberTourists.Items.Add("2");
            ddlNumberTourists.Items.Add("3");
        }
    }

    protected void btnProba_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblProba.Text = myche[0];
    }

    protected void btnReserve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        string num =Request.QueryString["ExcursionID"];
        Response.Redirect(String.Format("ClintsInformation.aspx?Excursiondate_ID={0}",num));

    }

    protected void ddlNumberTourists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int numTourists = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumberTourists.SelectedItem.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
        {

            Label myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.ID = "lblAccomodation" + (i + 1).ToString();
            myLabel.Text = "Настаняване Турист" + (i + 1).ToString();
            Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myLabel);
            DropDownList myDropDownList = new DropDownList();
            myDropDownList.ID = "ddlTourist" + i.ToString();
            Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myDropDownList);
            Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

            string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EXCURSIONSDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=true";
            string query =
      "SELECT Extra_Charge_ID, Excursion_ID, Amout, Extra_Charge_Description FROM EXTRA_CHARGES WHERE Excursion_ID=" + mynewstring;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int s = 0;

                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    mycheckbox.ID = "chkblextracharge" + i.ToString() + s.ToString();
                    mycheckbox.Items.Add(rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString());
                    Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mycheckbox);

                    if (mycheckbox.Items[s].Selected == true)
                    {  
                        myche.Add(mycheckbox.Items[s].Text);
                    }
                    s++;
                }

            }//End of try

            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
            Session["chk"] = myche;

        }//end of for
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly removing the pointless blank lines.

Comment: @Lion - You have enough reputation to make the edits and show the OP the right way to do it.

Comment: Please only post the _relevant_ code - posting all this code just makes it difficult to figure out the issue - things like the _line_ that caused the error and related code. I suggest following the guidelines of [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Empty catch blocks are a very bad coding practice - do not swallow exceptions like that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `myche` is empty before using `lblProba.Text = myche[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `myche` has no items in it when the button click event handler is triggered.

The only place you actually *add* any items to the list is in `ddlNumberTourists_SelectedIndexChanged`. This event handler is **not** called on post back, so `myche` is empty.

You need to store and load the values of `myche` in viewstate if you want them to be preserved between postbacks.

I suggest reading about the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as well as [TRULY Understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) if you want to understand how to get this to work properly.

---

Note on style:

```
try
{
  //something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

Is terrible practice - if an exception is thrown, you never know about it.

Comment: The problem is not only this Oded - according to me of course! I thing that   (mycheckbox.Items[s].Selected  is always false because when I create the items dynamically on creation they are not checked! I think that is teh first problem.

Comment: @MilkaSalkova - Well, there are plenty of things to point out, but I do suggest reading these two articles first.

Comment: yes I read them and i wan to store the text of the checked items in a session - i've worked with session and I wanted to try - so when I ignore this if (mycheckbox.Items[s].Selected == true ) and I store text of all the checkboxes in a session - it works perfectly. SO maybe my new question is where I should check if the items are checked If you can help me I will be glad

Comment: @MilkaSalkova - Well, that's a completely different question with different answers... I suggest you ask as a new question.